# OleFrame Cannot Save Excel Files

Tags: java, excel, swt, ole

I setup an application with an OLE frame for inplace editing. All is well for Word files, but saving Excel doesn't work. The save button of the Excel application is either grayed out (I guess when a non-OLE Excel is still open) or if it is not grayed out, it says "Refresh" (in German, but still) and does not save. No error message of any kind gets displayed.

`OleControlSite#save(File, boolean)` works, but we will not be able to explain to our customers why they cannot click the Excel save-button, so we need to fix it somehow.

A small demo to reproduce the problem:

```
public class OleDemoDialog extends Dialog {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OleDemoDialog dialog = new OleDemoDialog(new Shell());
    dialog.open();
}

protected OleDemoDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
    setShellStyle(getShellStyle()| SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
}

@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    OleFrame oleFrame = new OleFrame(parent, SWT.CLIP_CHILDREN);
    oleFrame.setBackground(JFaceColors.getBannerBackground(parent
            .getDisplay()));
    oleFrame.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    OleControlSite oleControlSite = new OleControlSite(oleFrame, SWT.NONE,
            new File("Mappe1.xlsx"));
    oleControlSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

    return oleFrame;
}

@Override
protected Point getInitialSize() {
    return new Point(600, 600);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you saw: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Working+with+OLE+Object+Frames ?

Comment: @HellBaby I did now, but I see no mention of the bug I described.

Answer (score -1):

> Save Excel Files using OleFrame.

```
OleClientSite clientSite.save(new File("D:\\JavaBooks.xlsx"), true);
```

I hope this example is useful.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class OleDemoDialog {

    OleClientSite clientSite;
    OleFrame oleFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        OleDemoDialog example = new OleDemoDialog();
        example.open(display);
    }

    public void open(Display display) {
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("OleDemoDialog Example");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Composite parent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, true));

        Composite buttons = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, false);
        buttons.setLayoutData(gridData);

        Composite displayArea = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        displayArea.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        displayArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 3, 1));

        Button openButton = new Button(buttons, SWT.NONE);
        openButton.setText("Open file");
        openButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                //new File("your File_Path.xlsx ")
                try {
                    clientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NONE, "Excel.Sheet", new File("D:\\JavaBooks.xlsx"));
                } catch (SWTException error) {error.printStackTrace();}
                if (clientSite != null)
                    clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
            }
        });
        new Label(buttons, SWT.NONE);

        Button excelButton = new Button(buttons, SWT.NONE);
        excelButton.setText("Save");
        excelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                clientSite.save(new File("D:\\JavaBooks.xlsx"), true);
                System.out.println("save..");
            }
        });

        oleFrame = new OleFrame(displayArea, SWT.NONE);
        shell.setSize(800, 600);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not address the problem at all.